# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith' error when trying to migrate legacy database in django

Tags: django, database, sqlite, migrate

Trying to migrate a legacy SQLite database (database.sqlite) in Django to inspect_db and pull model information from datbase.sqlite.  `python manage.py makemigrations` seems to be okay but when running `python manage.py migrate` there's an error.

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Tried to trackback error but got lost in all the code.

> Django==3.2.5
>
> python== 3.7.9

```
Running migrations:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/cp/Documents/dsi/django_project/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/cp/Documents/dsi/django_project/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/cp/Documents/dsi/django_project/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/cp/Documents/dsi/django_project/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/cp/Documents/dsi/django_project/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/cp/Documents/dsi/django_project/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 246, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/cp/Documents/dsi/django_project/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 91, in migrate
    self.recorder.ensure_schema()
  File "/Users/cp/Documents/dsi/django_project/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 68, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "/Users/cp/Documents/dsi/django_project/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 35, in __exit__
    self.connection.check_constraints()
  File "/Users/cp/Documents/dsi/django_project/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 347, in check_constraints
    self.ops.quote_name(primary_key_column_name),
  File "/Users/cp/Documents/dsi/django_project/django_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/operations.py", line 171, in quote_name
    if name.startswith('"') and name.endswith('"'):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

Here is settings.py database info(commented out other database for troubleshooting purposes.. commented out db.sqlite3 works fine):

```
DATABASES = {
      'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'database.sqlite',
    }

    
    # 'default': {
    #     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    #     'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    # }
}
```

Comment: Show your model / migration files.

Comment: I tried several things(different sqlite databses, removing all models, migrations) and the problem seems to be in a single table in the database I'm trying to migrate.
 * user_recommended BOOLEAN, 
 * chipped BOOLEAN, 
 * PRIMARY KEY (id), 
 * FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES user (id), 
 * FOREIGN KEY(grade_id) REFERENCES grade (id), 
 * FOREIGN KEY(method_id) REFERENCES method (id), 
 * CHECK (last_year IN (0, 1)), 
 * CHECK (climb_try IN (0, 1)), 
 CHECK (repeat IN (0, 1)), 
 CHECK (exclude_from_ranking IN (0, 1)), 
 CHECK (user_recommended IN (0, 1)), 
 CHECK (chipped IN (0, 1))

Comment: I'm not familiar with Check constraints in sqlite, but I suspect it has to do with those columns? or maybe the foreign keys?